# Can't figure out why border-radius css isn't working properly

Tags: html, css, squarespace

I'm working on a squarespace site with various convoluted divs and I can't get `border-radius` to work properly. I have been reading various threads with mixed replies on whether to place the `border-radius` property on the `img` or the `containing div`. Here's my current code on the img:

```css
#block-yui_3_17_2_1_1613415096810_5619 img {
    display: block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="sqs-block image-block sqs-block-image sqs-text-ready" data-block-type="5" id="block-yui_3_17_2_1_1613415096810_5619"><div class="sqs-block-content" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1613585600072_388">
    <div class="
          image-block-outer-wrapper
          layout-caption-below
          design-layout-inline
          combination-animation-none
          individual-animation-none
          individual-text-animation-none
        " data-test="image-block-inline-outer-wrapper" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1613585600072_387">
        <figure class="
              sqs-block-image-figure
              intrinsic
            " style="max-width:2500px;" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1613585600072_386">
          <div style="padding-bottom: 56.24%; overflow: hidden;" class="
                image-block-wrapper
                has-aspect-ratio
              " data-animation-role="image" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1613585600072_385">
            <noscript><img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/57f18cc8be659461b9d2a9ea/t/602ac5c3963d57265116477e/1613415902093/P1890464+%281%29.jpg" alt="P1890464 (1).jpg" /></noscript><img class="thumb-image loaded" data-src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/57f18cc8be659461b9d2a9ea/t/602ac5c3963d57265116477e/1613415902093/P1890464+%281%29.jpg" data-image="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/57f18cc8be659461b9d2a9ea/t/602ac5c3963d57265116477e/1613415902093/P1890464+%281%29.jpg" data-image-dimensions="2500x1406" data-image-focal-point="0.5,0.5" data-load="false" data-image-id="602ac5c3963d57265116477e" data-type="image" style="left: -0.0220265%; top: 0%; width: 100.044%; height: 100%; position: absolute;" alt="P1890464 (1).jpg" data-image-resolution="2500w" src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/57f18cc8be659461b9d2a9ea/t/602ac5c3963d57265116477e/1613415902093/P1890464+%281%29.jpg?format=2500w">
          </div>
        </figure>
    </div>
</div></div>
```

I'm a newb with css and I really have no idea where to place the border-radius property. Here is the general flow from the top level element on this item:

```
div > div > div > figure > div > img
```

Here is my Image: [image: current image] It shows up as an ellipse. I'm trying to make it a perfect circle with the image cropped to fit properly. I think maybe it's being thrown off by the image's aspect ratio.

If anyone has any ideas, I'd be very appreciative.

EDIT: here's the code of the IMG element

```
<img class="thumb-image loaded" data-src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/57f18cc8be659461b9d2a9ea/t/602ac5c3963d57265116477e/1613415902093/P1890464+%281%29.jpg" data-image="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/57f18cc8be659461b9d2a9ea/t/602ac5c3963d57265116477e/1613415902093/P1890464+%281%29.jpg" data-image-dimensions="2500x1406" data-image-focal-point="0.5,0.5" data-load="false" data-image-id="602ac5c3963d57265116477e" data-type="image" style="left: -0.0220265%; top: 0%; width: 100.044%; height: 100%; position: absolute;" alt="P1890464 (1).jpg" data-image-resolution="2500w" src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/57f18cc8be659461b9d2a9ea/t/602ac5c3963d57265116477e/1613415902093/P1890464+%281%29.jpg?format=2500w">
```

Comment: Please add a minimal reproduciable code snipept (ctrl + m) containing all necessary code (HTML and CSS) to reproduce the issue in your question directly.

Comment: Hey tacoshy, I'm not sure what other code to include. I will put the HTML of the img in my post but let me know if that's not what you need.

Comment: add the HTMl as you have it on your sdie with a full `source path`. I already edited your question to contain a snippet. Add enough code so that the issue can be reproduced which is also the first step for debugging. With the information you have provided so far, the issue can not be reproduced at our side and therefor we could only guess about the actual issue.

Comment: Ok with the edit of your code I see the actual issue. The issue is, that your image has an inline style. Inline style always have a higher priority then `css-style` and as such overwrite your `css-style`. Either remove the `inline-style` or add an `!important;` to the css style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Issue is, that your Image has an inline style:

```
<img style="left: -0.0220265%; 
            top: 0%; 
            width: 100.044%; 
            height: 100%; 
            position: absolute;">
```

An `inline-style` always has a higher priority then `css-style` and as such overwrites your css. Remove the height and width attribute and value and the issue will be fixed:

```css
#block-yui_3_17_2_1_1613415096810_5619 img {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
  object-position: 40% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="sqs-block image-block sqs-block-image sqs-text-ready" data-block-type="5" id="block-yui_3_17_2_1_1613415096810_5619">
  <div class="sqs-block-content" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1613585600072_388">
    <div class="
          image-block-outer-wrapper
          layout-caption-below
          design-layout-inline
          combination-animation-none
          individual-animation-none
          individual-text-animation-none
        " data-test="image-block-inline-outer-wrapper" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1613585600072_387">
      <figure class="
              sqs-block-image-figure
              intrinsic
            " style="max-width:2500px;" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1613585600072_386">
        <div style="padding-bottom: 56.24%; overflow: hidden;" class="
                image-block-wrapper
                has-aspect-ratio
              " data-animation-role="image" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1613585600072_385">
          <noscript><img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/57f18cc8be659461b9d2a9ea/t/602ac5c3963d57265116477e/1613415902093/P1890464+%281%29.jpg" alt="P1890464 (1).jpg" /></noscript><img class="thumb-image loaded" data-src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/57f18cc8be659461b9d2a9ea/t/602ac5c3963d57265116477e/1613415902093/P1890464+%281%29.jpg"
            data-image="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/57f18cc8be659461b9d2a9ea/t/602ac5c3963d57265116477e/1613415902093/P1890464+%281%29.jpg" data-image-dimensions="2500x1406" data-image-focal-point="0.5,0.5" data-load="false" data-image-id="602ac5c3963d57265116477e"
            data-type="image" style="left: -0.0220265%; top: 0%; position: absolute;" alt="P1890464 (1).jpg" data-image-resolution="2500w" src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/57f18cc8be659461b9d2a9ea/t/602ac5c3963d57265116477e/1613415902093/P1890464+%281%29.jpg?format=2500w">
        </div>
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternativly you can add `!important` to the `css-style` height and width value to give it the highest priority and overwrite the `inline style` as in the example below:

```css
#block-yui_3_17_2_1_1613415096810_5619 img {
  display: block;
  width: 200px !important;
  height: 200px !important;
  object-fit: cover;
  border-radius: 50%;
  object-position: 40% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="sqs-block image-block sqs-block-image sqs-text-ready" data-block-type="5" id="block-yui_3_17_2_1_1613415096810_5619">
  <div class="sqs-block-content" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1613585600072_388">
    <div class="
          image-block-outer-wrapper
          layout-caption-below
          design-layout-inline
          combination-animation-none
          individual-animation-none
          individual-text-animation-none
        " data-test="image-block-inline-outer-wrapper" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1613585600072_387">
      <figure class="
              sqs-block-image-figure
              intrinsic
            " style="max-width:2500px;" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1613585600072_386">
        <div style="padding-bottom: 56.24%; overflow: hidden;" class="
                image-block-wrapper
                has-aspect-ratio
              " data-animation-role="image" id="yui_3_17_2_1_1613585600072_385">
          <noscript><img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/57f18cc8be659461b9d2a9ea/t/602ac5c3963d57265116477e/1613415902093/P1890464+%281%29.jpg" alt="P1890464 (1).jpg" /></noscript><img class="thumb-image loaded" data-src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/57f18cc8be659461b9d2a9ea/t/602ac5c3963d57265116477e/1613415902093/P1890464+%281%29.jpg"
            data-image="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/57f18cc8be659461b9d2a9ea/t/602ac5c3963d57265116477e/1613415902093/P1890464+%281%29.jpg" data-image-dimensions="2500x1406" data-image-focal-point="0.5,0.5" data-load="false" data-image-id="602ac5c3963d57265116477e"
            data-type="image" style="left: -0.0220265%; top: 0%; width: 100.044%; height: 100%; position: absolute;" alt="P1890464 (1).jpg" data-image-resolution="2500w" src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/57f18cc8be659461b9d2a9ea/t/602ac5c3963d57265116477e/1613415902093/P1890464+%281%29.jpg?format=2500w">
        </div>
      </figure>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: Added `object-position: 40% 50%;` to "center" person in the image as asked at the comment section.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Since it's on squarespace I don't have access to the base html. I had to use the !important; method.

Comment: tacoshy, do you know how I can move the image within the circle, is that possible? I just need to move the image a little to the right so that it appears centered in the circle.

Comment: @Njserg try to add this to the css: `object-position: 40% 50%;` the default value is `50% 50%`. if you drop the first number below 50%, you will move the image further to the right.

Comment: @Njserg I added that codeline to the snippets to show that it works. Hope that works for you as you intended.

Answer (score -1):

You don't use img tag properly, You should make as following in HTML

```css
#img img {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div id="img">
      <div>
        <div>
          <figure>
            <img src="https://static1.squarespace.com/static/57f18cc8be659461b9d2a9ea/t/602ac5c3963d57265116477e/1613415902093/P1890464+%281%29.jpg?format=2500w">
          </figure>
        </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm trying to figure out how to include all the code. It's a giant mess due to squarespace.

Comment: Hey, no problem! Hope this helps you and thank you @ibram-reda for the review

Comment: Okay, I added the html into the snippet. I'm gonna try to fix the formatting so it's easier to read.

Comment: Could you paste your code on codepen so I can see and edit?

Comment: Hey Lucas, tacoshy's method worked. I had to use !important; to override the style. Thanks!

Comment: Great Njserg! The important thing is that you fixed it!

Answer (score -3):

For it to be a perfect circle you would need to make the image a square. I see you are attempting to do that by setting `width` and `height` properties, but they aren't working. This is probably due to the `object-fit: cover;` property.

Try taking that out and it may fix it.

Comment: Downvoted for following reasons: An anwser should be a definite solution not a guess. What you doing is simply guessing without any proof. This should have been given then as a comment instead. Also you're technically wrong. With a declared height and width, the image should be a square no matter if it is an inline or block level element. `object-fit: cover;` will not mess with it either which a simple test on your side could already proof.

Comment: Hey Brady, this didn't fix it, unfortunately. After adding this property, it didn't change the appearance at all.

Comment: @tacoshy Rightfully so. Thanks for the explanation.